# Is it possible to capture a variable from an Apache RewriteCond pattern match?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Using `mod_rewrite` I'd (ideally) like to capture a spacific ID from a URL in a variable from a `RewriteCond` pattern match for (e.g.)
`/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=984&Itemid=131`
to use it later in a `RewriteRule`.

I don't have a problem writing the pattern, but can't find out if this is actually possible, despite [reading the](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). Has anyone else tried this or know it to be impossible?

The site is built on Joomla 1.6 (which adds IDs to SEO-friendly URLs), and I'm trying to avoid the overhead of something like [HP Router](http://www.joomlager.de/hp-router) just to change one particular group of URLs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work.  You can use a `%` sign to access the groups from the `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Itemid=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /some/page/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! Will  be working on the site next week so will test and click 'accept' then :-)

Comment: Thanks - answers my question, but the rewriting I need turns out to be too complex to use mod_rewrite easily